# Bitbake cannot find the header file of another recipe

Tags: header-files, yocto, bitbake

I am having a package which is depending on asterisk. As it is depending on asterisk I included DEPENDS = "asterisk" in bitbake file.But my source package cannot locate "asterisk.h" which is available in asterisk package.I tried "bitbake asterisk -c listtasks" in this command [do_populate_sysroot] was available.But from where bitbake is expecting the asterisk.h to reside, so that it can fetch from there.
Following is the log error I am getting while compiling my recipe.

```
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
 checking for sys/time.h... (cached) yes
 checking for termios.h... (cached) yes
 checking whether asterisk.h in ../include... no
 checking whether asterisk.h in /usr/include... no
 checking whether asterisk.h in /usr/local/include... no
 checking whether asterisk.h in /opt/local/include... no
 configure: error: Can't find "asterisk.h"
```

NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.

Comment: Can you try `oe-pkgdata-utils list-pkg-files -p asterisk` to see if it contains asterisk.h file? Which recipe do you use for asterisk?

Comment: Yes with the command you given asterisk.h is available   asterisk-dev:
 /usr/include/asterisk.h.I am using asterisk from 'meta-telephony'.(osmocom git-branch).

Comment: Which Yocto version do you use? Can you post your recipe? You can try with more recent asterisk [recipe](https://github.com/ctrob67/meta-telephony/blob/master/recipes-asterisk/asterisk/asterisk_13.17.2.bb).

Comment: I am using the same recipe as what you have mentioned.Here is my recipe [file](https://pastebin.com/C5HxjtHv).

Comment: Yocto version "sumo"

Comment: Yocto use separate sysroot to build recipes, so you don't need to add do_populate_sysroot stuff. Used sysroot can be found in `build/tmp/work/<arch>/<pkg>/recipe-sysroot`

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in your autotools scripts which does not allow cross-compiler overloads?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Bitbake file of asterisk is not doing complete installation in do_install_append() only "oe_runmake DISTDIR=${D} samples command is available.But before this I want to do "oe_runmake DISTDIR=${D} install".If i directly write the install command it is not installing. how can I append more make commands like (make install,make samples) in do_install_append().So that it will keep all header in sysroot.

Comment: do_install_append allows to override/add some steps that are not already executed by do_install. In Asterisk case, as do_install is not defined, it is executed with default oe_runmake options, and you shouldn't have to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use provider and user to illustrate this case, the package (recipe) provides a header file to be used by another package (recipe) is the provider, the package (recipe) use a header file from another package (recipe) is the user.

First we change the provider's recipe (myprovider.bb) to export the header file -- myapi.h,

```
...
do_install() {

    install -d ${D}/${bindir}
    install -m 755 ${B}/hello_provider ${D}/${bindir}

    install -d ${D}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/myapi.h ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/
}
...
```

Secondly we change the user's recipe (myuser.bb) to refer the header file -- myapi.h

```
...
do_compile () {    

    ${CC} ${WORKDIR}/main.c -o hello_user ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/lib_myprovider/ 
}

# file dependency declaration
FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/lib_myprovider"

# package dependency declaration
DEPENDS += "myprovider"
...
```

At last, rebuild myprovider.bb and myuser.bb recipes, it should work.